# can't make a shell script to make a jar file

Tags: java, bash, jar

I try to make a simple shell script to make a jar file. The jar command combined with `-C` does not work with wildcards. Therefor I use a wildcard to find the files I want. Write them to a file, and loop over them.

It looks something like this:

```
the_classes=''

cd "$bin_folder"
tmp_dir=$(mktemp -d -t java_sucks)
find "imui/core/" -type f -name "IMUI_Widget_Agent*.class" >"$tmp_dir/classes.txt" 

while IFS="" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ]
do
    the_classes="${the_classes} -C '$bin_folder' '$p'"

done < "$tmp_dir/classes.txt"
```

Using the above I complete the command:

```
cmd='jar cfm build/IMUI_Widget_Agent.jar'
cmd="${cmd} \"$bin_folder/imui/core/IMUI_Widget_Agent_MANIFEST.MF\" $the_classes"

printf "\n\n\ncmd\n\n\n"

echo $cmd
```

**Now if I copy and paste this command to execute it works!**

But I want to avoid the manual labour of doing the copy and paste by hand every time.

Now I have:

```
eval "$("$cmd")"
```

But I get an error `File name too long`. No matter what I try, every fix I do creates a new problem. I have been working 6 hours now to make this script.

What would be a good step forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you `cd "$bin_folder"` you don't actually need `-C "$bin_folder"`:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
cd "$bin_folder"
jar cfm build/IMUI_Widget_Agent.jar \
    imui/core/IMUI_Widget_Agent_MANIFEST.MF \
    imui/core/**/IMUI_Widget_Agent*.class
```

However, if you still want to add them as part of a larger script, you can easily and robustly build your command in an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
cmd=(jar cfm build/IMUI_Widget_Agent.jar imui/core/IMUI_Widget_Agent_MANIFEST.MF)

cd "$bin_folder"
for file in imui/core/**/IMUI_Widget_Agent*.class
do
  cmd+=(-C "$bin_folder" "$file")
done

echo "About to execute: "
printf "%q " "${cmd[@]}"
echo

"${cmd[@]}"
```

Alternatively, you can simply do `eval "$cmd"` with your code, which is equivalent to echo and copy-pasting. However, be aware that this is fragile and error prone because it requires careful escaping of the filenames which you're not currently doing.

Comment: Hi, this looks clean, but my bash does not support `shopt -s globstar` and I don't want to update cause it will mean others will run into the same problem.

Comment: The same code works with macOS's `zsh` if you just switch the shebang and delete the `shopt -s globstar`

Comment: For now it seems it also to work if I remove `shopt -s globstar`. Thank you so much, I had the thing working before your answer but what I wrote was such a pain to read and maintain.

Comment: If you use bash, then `**` is equivalent to `*` and only searches one level. If that's enough, then great. Otherwise, you can also rewrite your `find` and `while` loop to append to an array instead.